# Как обратиться к переменной из другого файла функций? (котлин, андроид)

Tags: android, kotlin

Действия программы такие: объявляется переменная, ей присваивается значение из поля, в дальнейшем с ней производятся какие-то действия (функции все будут во втором файле), новое значение заносится в поле, для очистки поля по нажатию на кнопку значение стирается. И кнопка, и поля в одном фрагменте активити, активити одно.

В MainAktivity.kt

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    public var date1 : EditText? = null
    public var date2 : EditText? = null
    public val dataString1: String = date1?.text.toString()
    public val dataString2: String = date2?.text.toString()
    ............
    btnRunClear.setOnClickListener {
        this.ClearAll()
    }
```

в MyFuncs.kt (date1 и date2 подсвечиваются красным цветом, ошибка Unresolved reference, использование fun Activity.ClearAll() та же ошибка)

```
fun Context.ClearAll() {
    this.date1?.text?.clear()
    this.date2?.text?.clear()
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: вероятно стоит взять учебник и ознакомиться с основами языка и ООП. Почитать про области видимости переменных, например. С чего вы взяли, что date1 в этих двух файлах - одна и та же переменная???

Comment: знаю что переменная видна только в границах своей функции, она объявлена в активити, а активити одно, нужен способ обратиться к ней из другого файла. `Paths.get()` не подойдет? если дадите ссылку на конкретное теоретическое пояснение по данному вопросу буду благодарен. А иначе можно на любые вопросы так отвечать )

Comment: нет, не на любые. А только на те, ответы на которые есть в учебниках. Ну или хотя бы легко находятся с помощью поиска. На этом сайте в правой колонке даже предлагается список похожих вопросов.

Comment: конечно я смотрю решения перед тем как задать вопрос. Но в одном месте советуют _объявить переменную в качестве поля класса._ `private val timer: CountDownTimer`, тут же называют это костылем. Другое предложение , которым я и воспользовался "_Сделайте из функции `exitSid экстеншен-функцию: fun Context.exitSid()`_". Других здесь тем нет (сбоку). В интернете есть решения про передачу переменных из разных активити. Не мой случай

Comment: есть ещё такой ответ (https://techarks.ru/qa/dostup-k-peremennim-v-kotlin-7X/) но, применить его не получается, хотя можно было и передать все очищаемые поля списком `val listDataString = listOf(dataString1, dataString2, dataString3, dataString4)` затем `var allDataString = MainActivity().listDataString` и уже из другого файла к allDataString обратиться....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В экстеншен функции Context.ClearAll() "this" - это Context.
У Context нет полей date1 и date2.
Вы можете поменять Context.ClearAll() на MainActivity.ClearAll() или использовать
ClearAll() как функцию класса MainActivity. Тогда вы избежите "Unresolved reference".

И пара советов на последок: Не используйте фичи языка которые вы не понимаете(зачем вам экстеншен?). Подтяните понимание ООП. Почитайте за код стайл в котлине(название методов принято писать с маленькой буквы, если писать с большой - можно при беглом прочтении путать с Классом). И внятно формулируйте желаемый результат.

Comment: по вашему решению сделал, но не работает - смотрите скриншот, добавил в сам вопрос темы. Хотя сам код передается из одного файла в другой (проверял на Toast). Может потому что поля находятся во `tools:context=".FirstFragment">`. То есть во фрагменте. Получается что само обращение к полю не срабатывает

Comment: поля не стираются

Comment: public var date1 : EditText? = null
    public var date2 : EditText? = null
У вас эти поля не инициализированы, точнее инициализированы значением null.
Да и я не уверен что метод clear() - делает именно то что вы от него ожидаете

Comment: значит сначала надо туда занести значение? а то что я с клавиатуры ввожу в эмуляторе значения, а они не стираются ?.....

Comment: прошу прощения за разбор академических вещей, но я new в программировании. Изначально код был построен на одной активитити и в одном файле MainActivity. Сейчас я усложнил структуру, добавил два фрагмента и решил все пользовательские функции вывести в отдельный файл. Кратко смысл программы был таким - https://pastebin.com/mrYdMEMa. И все работало

Comment: в принципе вообще не получается туда что-то записать https://iscr.ru/images/2021/08/04/KOD5.png, может эти поля во фрагменте надо объявлять?

Comment: отловил ошибку -

Comment: 2021-08-04 19:58:22.429 5435-5435/ru.jurvrn.sid E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: ru.jurvrn.sid, PID: 5435
    java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text 'null' could not be parsed at index 0
    at  java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:1949)
        at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1851)
        at java.time.LocalDate.parse(LocalDate.java:394)
        at ru.jurvrn.sid.MyFuncsKt.resumeSid(MyFuncs.kt:26)
        at ru.jurvrn.sid.MainActivity.onStart$lambda-1(MainActivity.kt:98)

Comment: получается что код просто не видит эти поля

Comment: Не сочтите за грубость, но получается вам нужно сначала выучить язык на котором вы хотите писать(в частности инициализация переменных и концепции null), а уже потом осваивать фреймворк андроида.
"значит сначала надо туда занести значение? а то что я с клавиатуры ввожу в эмуляторе значения, а они не стираются ?...." - Ознакомитесь с понятиями ссылок, полей и классов и ситуация проясница. Тут принято отвечать на один конкретно поставленный вопрос, а не давать вводный курс ООП.

Comment: не сочту, учу теорию вместе с практикой :). Вам спасибо за помощь, а теперь сам понял - код по инициализации и объявления полей и кнопки надо было перенести во фрагмент )) а потом оказалось findViewById во фрагменте не работает )). В итоге в начале фрагмента делаю public var date1: EditText? = null, а в onViewCreated date1 = binding.fieldDate1,? а потом вызов по кнопке функции clearAll() из другого файла (по вашему решению, только заменил на fun FirstFragment.clearAll() {), а потом простая команда date1?.text?.clear() . I'm so glad)